# How do I make sure http links to my app work on a real Android device using a browser?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make sure my app links work on a real device. Here is my Xamarin code:

---

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", Label = "MyappName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "http",
DataHost = "www.mywebsite.net",
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

---

Here is what works:

- Link from www.myotherwebsite.net (in a browser) to www.mywebsite.net, using a virtual device. Android asks me to choose if I want to open www.mywebsite.net with my browser or just open my app.
- Link to app from e-mail (tested with gmail app, outlook app, and Android e-mail app) using a real device. Android asks me the same question as described above.

Here is what not works:

- Link from www.myotherwebsite.net (in a browser) to www.mywebsite.net, using a real device. Android does not ask me if I want to open my app. It just opens www.mywebsite.net .

How do I make sure this works? Such a mechanisme should work on real devices. For wikipedia, it does work.

Comment: Maybe the browser wants "www.mywebsite.net/myapp.apk"? I've never done this so idk...just a thought

Comment: The wikipedia app does not need that. So I think my app does not as well.